# Change specific values in an array

Tags: swift

I have 3 arrays of type Int that have 5 values in each in them. I'm trying to create a function that replaces the values based on conditions. For example, array1, if a value of an index is between 2-5, replace with a randomly generated number between 1-6.

Here is what I have so far

```
import Foundation

func newRandomNumbers(#array1: [Int], array2: [Int], array3: [Int]) {

for i in 0..<5 {
    switch (array1[i]) {
    case 2, 3, 4, 5:
        let randomNumber = Int(1 + arc4random() % 6)
        array1[i] = randomNumber

        break;

    default:
        break;
    }

    switch (array2[i]) {
    case 2, 3, 4, 5:

        array2[i]
        break;
    default:
        break;
    }

    switch (array3[i]) {
    case 1, 2, 3, 4, 5:

        array3[i]
        break;
    default:
        break;
    }
}
}
```

I get an error " Cannot assign to immutable value of type 'Int'"

When I rewrite a simplified function that does the same purpose I don't get the error, but strangely not all the numbers are replaced.

```
import Foundation


var newArray = [2,3,4,5,6]

func newRandom(#array1: [Int]){
    for i in 0..<5 {
        switch(array1[i]) {
           case 2, 3, 4, 5:
              let randomNumber = Int(1 + arc4random() % 6)
              newArray[1] = randomNumber
           default:
              break;
        }
   }
}

newRandom(array1: newArray)

newArray
```

Not sure how to resolve. Recommendations on how to clean up my code would also be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: put   newArray[i] = randomNumber  instead of   newArray[1] = randomNumber

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Cannot assign to immutable value of type 'Int'" is because the parameters are actually constants. You can read the line:

```
func newRandomNumbers(#array1: [Int], array2: [Int], array3: [Int])
```

as:

```
func newRandomNumbers(#array1 let array1: [Int], let array2: [Int], let array3: [Int])
```

You can change it by putting `var` in front of the parameter and return the array. Another option is using `&` to make it a reference, so you don't have to return a new array.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you look into the array's map function:
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Reference/SwiftStandardLibraryReference/Array.html

you would use for example:

```
array.map {
   if ($0 satisfies condition) {
       generate random number 
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `inout` for each of your function parameters and add `&` before your variable name when calling the function, it will **modify the array in place**:

```
func newRandom(inout myArray: [Int]) {
    for (index, element) in enumerate(myArray) {
        switch element {
        case 2...5:
            myArray[index] = Int(1 + arc4random() % 6)
        default:
            break
        }
    }
}

var newArray = [2,3,4,5,6]
newRandom(&newArray)
println(newArray) // "newArray" was modified, contains random numbers
```

Note:

```
switch element {
case 2...5:
```

is equivalent to:

```
if element >= 2 && element <= 5 {
```

**SWIFT 2.0 UPDATE:**

As of Swift 2.0, `enumerate` is now to be called on the sequence itself. Also, `println` has been deprecated in favor of `print`:

```
func newRandom(inout myArray: [Int]) {
    for (index, element) in myArray.enumerate() {
        switch element {
        case 2...5:
            myArray[index] = Int(1 + arc4random() % 6)
        default:
            break
        }
    }
}

var newArray = [2,3,4,5,6]
newRandom(&newArray)
print(newArray)
```